# How to create a column expression using a subquery in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given any df, I want to calculate another column for the df called "has_duplicates", and then add a column with a boolean value for whether each row is unique. Example input df:

```
val df = Seq((1, 2), (2, 5), (1, 7), (1, 2), (2, 5)).toDF("A", "B")
```

Given an input `columns: Seq[String]`, I know how to get the count of each row:

```
val countsDf = df.withColumn("count", count("*").over(Window.partitionBy(columns.map(col(_)): _*)))
```

But I'm not sure how to use this to create a column expression for the final column indicating whether each row is unique.

Something like

```
def getEvaluationExpression(df: DataFrame): Column = {
    when("count > 1", lit("fail").otherwise(lit("pass"))
 }
```

but the count needs to be evaluated on the spot using the query above.

Comment: Are you asking an udf? so confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
scala> df.withColumn("has_duplicates", when(count("*").over(Window.partitionBy(df.columns.map(col(_)): _*)) > 1 , lit("fail")).otherwise("pass")).show(false)
+---+---+--------------+
|A  |B  |has_duplicates|
+---+---+--------------+
|1  |7  |pass          |
|1  |2  |fail          |
|1  |2  |fail          |
|2  |5  |fail          |
|2  |5  |fail          |
+---+---+--------------+
```

**Or**

```
scala> df.withColumn("count",count("*").over(Window.partitionBy(df.columns.map(col(_)): _*))).withColumn("has_duplicates", when($"count" > 1 , lit("fail")).otherwise("pass")).show(false)
+---+---+-----+--------------+
|A  |B  |count|has_duplicates|
+---+---+-----+--------------+
|1  |7  |1    |pass          |
|1  |2  |2    |fail          |
|1  |2  |2    |fail          |
|2  |5  |2    |fail          |
|2  |5  |2    |fail          |
+---+---+-----+--------------+
```

Comment: These answers are adding a column to the DF. I am looking something that simply generates the new column expression. Signature: `def getEvaluationExpression(df: DataFrame): Column.` Is the only way to do `df.withColumn.col('has_duplicates')`?